# How to generate makefile targets from variables?

Tags: makefile, parallel-processing, gnu

I currently have a makefile to process some data.  The makefile gets the inputs to the data processing by sourcing a CONFIG file, which defines the input data in a variable.  Currently, I symlink the input files to a local directory, i.e. the makefile contains:

```
tmp/%.txt: tmp
    ln -fs $(shell echo $(INPUTS) | tr ' ' '\n' | grep $(patsubst tmp/%,%,$@)) $@
```

This is not terribly elegant, but appears to work.  Is there a better way?  Basically, given

INPUTS = /foo/bar.txt /zot/snarf.txt

The above will link all input files into tmp/, so that I can process them with rules like

```
%.out: tmp/%.txt
    some command
```

As well as targets to merge results depending on all $(INPUT) files.

Also, apart from the kludgosity, the makefile doesn't work correctly with -j, something that is crucial for the analysis to complete in reasonable time.  I guess that's a bug in GNU make, but any hints welcome.

Comment: Have you tried it? GNU make support that syntax you want.

Comment: I replaced the kludge with another one, unconditionally linking all inputs as part of the initialization of a variable.  That seems to work, and no longer hangs make when using -j.

    LINKTMPFILES := $(shell mkdir -p tmp/; rm tmp/*; ln -fs $(INPUTS) tmp/)
      :
    %.out: %.txt
        some command

Still not a paragon of elegance, but...  *** Sorry about the mess, but I'm not allowed by SO to post it as a separate answer ***

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Uh, could you perhaps be more specific?

Comment: I meant that the `%.out: %.txt` target works. Maybe I just misunderstood your phrasing.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this?

```
TARGET = x
INPUT  = a.txt b.txt
OUTPUT = $(INPUT:%.txt=%.out)

.PHONY: default
default: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OUTPUT)
    cat $^ > $@

%.out: %.txt
    cp $< $@
```

Tried with the `-j` option to `make`, but for such a simple example it's easy to resolve the dependencies and build in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Several things here:

- `make` will take care of the list of inputs. There's no need to use `tr` and such. You can do everything you want with `make` functions, such as `patsubst`.
- `make` works well with `-j`. If it does not work as you expected, then it means that you didn't express all your mind in the rules and dependencies.
- You wrote about merging your outputs. The cause of the previous bullet may be here. You have to instruct `make` that your merged target depend on all your `.out` targets. Then, `make` will wait for all targets before merging.
- I guess there's no need to create symlinks to your `.txt` source files. I'm pretty sure you can write pattern rules that use the input files where they are. You have to allow the output files to be in various subdirectories.

It would end up with something along the lines of:

```
OUTPUTS = $(patsubst %.txt, out/%.out, $(INPUTS))

out/%.out: %.txt
    <some command>

merged: $(OUTPUTS)
    <merge command>
```

Comment: The problem in you example is that the input (txt) files reside in the current directory, while I'd like to import them from arbitrary locations.  I know about patsubst et al, but I couldn't work out how to do exactly this (i.e. select one item from a list in a variable).

Comment: There's no problem with this. Your input files can be anywhere. It will create subdirectories besides directory `out` that match the full source path.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `vpath` to let make find the input files. You can then simply work with file names without the directory parts. Something like this should work. (The `$(sort ...)` is there to remove duplicates; not absolutely necessary.)

```
INPUTS  := ...
OUTPUTS := $(patsubst %.txt, %.out, $(notdir $(INPUTS))

vpath %.txt $(sort $(dir $(INPUTS)))

merged.txt: $(OUTPUTS)
    <merge command> $^ -o $@

%.out: %.txt
    <some command> $< -o $@
```

This solution relies on there not being duplicate file names, but I think you implied that condition by creating the symlinks.

Comment: I didn't know about VPATH, it looks like it might be what I want, yes.  Thanks!